# My function from js file is not getting called from html file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html

I am working on a website which used node js. I added a function in my js file. Now when I am trying to call the function from the html page the function is not getting called. 
This is the code which I used in the html page:

```
<div id ="bubble" class="bubble-style" data-action="getSpeechBubble()</div>
```

I just added a console statement in the function :

```
getSpeechBubble: function() {

        console.log(' getSpeechBubble ');
}
```

Comment: And how are you calling that? Also please format the code properly

Comment: How are you calling the function? How are you including the JS file? Are you sure it's not cacheing? Are there any errors in the console? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: The HTML isn't valid and the JS isn't depending on how you've declared it

Comment: What happens when you add the quotation mark here and > `<div id ="bubble" class="bubble-style" data-action="getSpeechBubble()"></div>` ?

Comment: @vlaz I am calling the function using the "data-action" tag. No its not caching. If I add a img tag in my div and add a image, I can see that but I don't find my console statement .

Comment: @AndrewLi Can you please tell me what is the right way. I am a newbie to web development.

Comment: @AndroidGeek you _have_ the function in the `data-action` attribute - whether it's being called is really hard to say, especially considering you haven't closed the quotes but other than that, it also depends on what is using that attribute. And it seems like you've defined that function inside an object but you haven't included the object either in the `data-action` attribute nor in the code snippet you've posted here, so it might be incorrect syntax. There is hardly anything that we can guess from what you've posted aside from the unclosed quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to create and call functions, most popular used is below

```js
function getSpeechBubble(){
console.log("getSpeechBubble");
}
//get function from data-action attribute
var exc = document.getElementById("bubble").getAttribute("data-action");

//or window.addEventListener("load",new Function(exc),false);
window.onload = new Function(exc);
//or .addEventListener("clik",new Function(exc),false);
document.getElementById("bubble").onclick = new Function(exc);
```

```html
<div id ="bubble" class="bubble-style" data-action="getSpeechBubble()">
click me
</div>
```

```
//1st way
this.getSpeechBubble = function() {
            console.log(' 1st way: getSpeechBubble ');
}
this.getSpeechBubble();
//2nd way
this["getSpeechBubble"] = function() {
            console.log(' 2nd way: getSpeechBubble ');
}
this["getSpeechBubble"]();
//3rd way
window["getSpeechBubble"] = function() {
            console.log(' 3rd way: getSpeechBubble ');
}
window["getSpeechBubble"]()
//4th way
var getSpeechBubble = function() {
            console.log(' 4th way: getSpeechBubble ');
}
getSpeechBubble();
//5th way
var js = {
getSpeechBubble: function(){
            console.log(' 5th way: getSpeechBubble ');
}
};
js.getSpeechBubble();
//6th way
function getSpeechBubble () {
            console.log(' 6th way: getSpeechBubble ');
}
getSpeechBubble();
```